# Not able to get to API controller in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to use a Blazor Server that I would like to do both a UI and host an API. I created a Controllers folder and added a API Controller to it. I've added what I think I need to the Program.cs file to add the ability to use an API Controller. I can start up and build the project but when I use Postman to try to get to the end point, I keep getting an error that says:

> "Sorry, there's nothing at this address.".

This is my Postman GET call: https://localhost:7131/api/GetApplicationNames

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using UsersAdmin_BlazorServer.Data;
using UsersAdmin_BlazorServer.Interfaces;
using UsersAdmin_BlazorServer.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IAppManager, AppManager>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDataManager, DataManager>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

//Adds DataContext dependency
var connString = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DbConnection"];
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connString);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

AppController.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class AppController : ControllerBase
{
        private readonly ILogger<AppController> _log;
        private readonly IAppManager _appManager;
        private readonly IDataManager _dataManager;

        public AppController(ILogger<AppController> log, IAppManager appManager, IDataManager dataManager)
        {
            _log = log;
            _appManager = appManager;
            _dataManager = dataManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/GetApplicationNames")]
        public List<string> GetApplicationNames()
        {
            List<string> listApplicationNames = new List<string>();

            listApplicationNames = _dataManager.GetApplicationNames();

            return listApplicationNames;
        }
}
```

Comment: I think UseRouting should be before MapControllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do to add controllers in a blazor server app is
create the controller and use `AddControllers()` and `MapControllers()`

However your problem here is the "/" on your route attribute
try

```
 [Route("GetApplicationNames")]
```

and your controller should work.